# how to add item to a VB6 2D array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vb6

I'm using a 2D array for storing users username and password. `users` defined as global string array:

```
Dim users(9, 2) As String
```

How to add a user to that array? set username and password at once.

Comment: Probably a better model would be a collection/array of classes.

Answer (score 8):

Once you have `Dim` the array users with explicit bounds, you can't `ReDim` it.
You can try this, it won't compile (Array already dimensioned)

```
Dim users(9, 2) As String
ReDim Preserve users(10, 2) ' doesn't compile!
```

Another issue you will have will be trying to `ReDim Preserve` the first index of the array. You can try that too, you will get runtime error (Subscript out of range)

```
Dim users() As String
ReDim Preserve users(0, 1)
ReDim Preserve users(1, 1) ' runtime error!
```

Instead, I came up with the following. You will need to keep the first index to distinguish between `username` or `password`. This will be size 1 (not 2). The second index will increase as you add more users:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim users() As String
    ReDim users(1, 0)
    Add users, "name1", "pw1"
    Add users, "name2", "pw2"
End Sub

Private Sub Add(ByRef users() As String, username As String, password As String)
    If Not (users(0, 0) = vbNullString And users(1, 0) = vbNullString) Then
        ReDim Preserve users(1, UBound(users, 2) + 1)
    End If
    users(0, UBound(users, 2)) = username
    users(1, UBound(users, 2)) = password
End Sub
```

If you can't swap the username and password, you might want to look into a different data structure such as collection, or array of a custom class with username and password fields.

Answer (score 4):

create a user defined type containing all fields

```
Private Type UserData
  strName As String
  strPass As String
End Type
```

and then create an array of that user defined type

```
Dim udtUser() As UserData
ReDim udtUser(9) As UserData
With udtUser(9)
  .strName = "captain hook"
  .strPass = "parrotname"
End With 'udtUser(9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the users and assign values to the aray directly:

```
Dim cntr As Integer
For cntr = 0 To UBound(cntr) - 1
    users(x, 0) = "username"
    users(x, 1) = "password"
Next cntr
```